# Speakers Whooshing

Tags: sound, speakers

Some days ago the speakers of my laptop started whooshing after a few hours. Now they're whooshing all the time (it starts during the boot process). How can I make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! :)

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 20
echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'
```

Place this script in `/etc/init.d/makeSpeakersStopWhooshing.sh` and run:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/makeSpeakersStopWhooshing.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99MakeSpeakersStopWhooshing
```

Restart your machine for it to take effect (or execute `echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'` manually if you don't feel like restarting).

This assumes that your computer accomplishes certain tasks after a certain amount of time. If it doesn't work because you have a slow PC, maybe change the 20 to some higher number.